# Cant fix my if-else condition in login.php

Tags: php, database, if-statement, post

I have created a condition to check if name and password are correct the only issue here is when i test it it goes complete the opposite of what i want. It doesnt matter if i put it right or wrong the message will always be "You have successfuly logged in". Im using PDO just to know

```
<?php
  include('connection.php');

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $data = $_POST;
 
  $statment = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM registration WHERE name = :name AND password = :password');

  if($statment){
    $result = $statment->execute([
        ':name' => $data['name'],
        ':password' => $data['password']
    ]);
   } 



  if($data['name'] == $name && $data['password'] == $password){
       echo 'You have successfuly logged in';
  }else {
       die('Incorrect username or password');
  } 


 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made your script overly complicated .. The easiest way is to bind and execute ..  Then you can simply check if there are any rows, and THEN compare with your `data` array created from the executed statement.

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $statment = $connection->prepare("SELECT name, password FROM registration 
                                       WHERE name = ? AND password = ?");
    $statment ->bind_param("ss", $name, $password);
    $statment ->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

   if ($result ->num_rows > 0) {
       $data = $result->fetch_array();
   }else{
       echo "No results found";
   }

   if($data['name'] == $name && $data['password'] == $password){
       echo 'You have successfuly logged in';
  }else {
       die('Incorrect username or password');
  } 
?>
```

(bear in mind I wrote that freehand, and it has not been tested or debugged, but the principals are there)

**ON A SIDE NOTE**

That being said .. You should never be storing passwords in a open "text" field.  You should be encrypting them.  The easiest way is to use `bcrypt` to build out a hash:

```
$options = [
   'cost' => 12,
];

$newPass =  password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

And store that in your database .. Then you can compare it like so ..

```
 if (password_verify($pss, $pwdCheck)
```

`$pss` being what was sent in from the form .. and `$pwdCheck` being the hash you SELECTED from the database -- Brought into your current code set, would look something like:

```
if($data['name'] == $name && password_verify($password, $data['password']){
```

Comment: Hi there thank you for your answer, yes you were right about bind_param and to be honest using mysqli is much better but anyway thanks for help